# Messenger connect desktop API for Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-live-id

Is there Messenger Connect API for Windows Phone 7 to use in Silverlight phone application to allow user authentication with windows live id and get a user consent to share profile data with my app? It all works great for PC desktop app or ASP.Net. I want the same experience for my users with the phone: login using windows live id and access the same data they can access on their desktop through a web site or desktop app. The backend is, obviously, multi-tenant, one database, many app users - everyone sees his own data based on his windows live id.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Randolph demonstrated some interaction with the messenger api's here if you'd like to check it out.

[Windows Phone 7 Beta with Windows Live Messenger Connect](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/07/26/Windows-Phone-7-Beta-with-Windows-Live-Messenger-Connect.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mick, the title looks promissing, but I can't access the page (You are not authorized to view this page).

Comment: Seems to be a temporary problem...  Yes, I've actually seen this article already. I guess I need to try this. But I was just wondering if there is a MS library for messanger connect API that would work on windows phone. Does not seem to be a big deal to just port what MS already have for desktop to the phone. Would be damn nice.

Comment: That doesn't exist on the phone at the moment. You can always comment on their suggestion forum though.